# Number of the Year's week formula stopped working

Tags: formula, date

I had a nice formula that was counting the week of the year, but as we approach the end of year it has stopped working. It now shows "1" in December.
Sample versions:

```
    CEILING((( Date__c - DATE(YEAR( Date__c ), 1, 1) + 1) +
MOD(DATE(YEAR( Date__c ), 1, 1) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)) / 7)
```

also getting 1 back is:

```
FLOOR( (
Date__c - DATE( YEAR( Date__c),1,1) +
MOD( DATE(YEAR(Date__c),1,1) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7)
) / 7)
+ 1
```

Does anyone know a formula that is working now?
thanks
Related: this formula for Current Week of the year is off, too, showing 3 on Jan 4th of the year:

```
MOD(FLOOR( ( TODAY() -DATEVALUE("2006-01-01" ))/7),52)+1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SFDC Common Date Formulas Doc](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/16/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_useful_formula_fields.pdf) uses this formula

```
IF(
   CEILING( ( date - DATE( YEAR( date ), 1, 1) + 1) / 7) > 52,
   52,
   CEILING( ( date - DATE( YEAR( date ), 1, 1) + 1) / 7)
)
```

> You can find the current week by determining how many days there have
>   been in the current year and dividing that value by 7. The IF()
>   statement ensures that the week number the formula returns doesn’t
>   exceed 52. So if the given date is December 31 of the given year, the
>   formula returns 52, even though it’s more than 52 weeks after the week
>   of January.

Comment: this is a common problem with hand rolled Date processing, because there is 52.14 weeks in a year, and people just assume they can calculate date-weeks by dividing down the date themselves, and then in the last 4 days of the year it starts going wrong. There are a number of ways (including this) to deal with it, but the key thing is to remember it will affect you when you are coding!! you obvs get my point tho + happy Christmas

Comment: @SimonLawrence -- I'm just "a-quoting from the SFDC doc"

Comment: ah yeah! by "get my point" I meant "get my vote" because what you posted was absolutely right!! sorry, it sounded like I was talking down at you :D

Comment: @simonLawrence lol - and enjoy the holidays

Comment: Thanks. Relatedly, I have a calculator field for "Current Week" and right now on Jan 4th it's showing 3. I will add to the question for your reference and try the suggested method.